# How to replace IN by AND in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT patient_id, patient_name
FROM patient
WHERE patient_id IN ('p37', 'p78', 'p87')
```

How can I separate `IN` into multiple `AND` statements? If I put:

```
SELECT patient_id, patient_name
FROM patient
WHERE patient_id='p37' AND patient_id='p78' AND patient_id='p87'
```

it returns an empty result.

We know that `IN` can be used in place of multiple `AND` statements, so what's going wrong with this query?

Comment: Your request really doesn't make sense; how can a patient have three different IDs?  Also, you misunderstand `IN()`; it functions as an `OR`, nor `AND`.

Comment: What's wrong with the IN query you have? Is it not giving you the desired result?

Comment: ok thanks broo i got it its or instead of and

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvoted. It seems to me to be a legit question whose result enforces the correct understanding of SQL. I'm sure @Marwan now knows how IN works and can pass that knowledge on to others. As for a valid query, it seems reasonable if the code is meant to find a specific set of patients.

Answer (score 2):

IN is based on OR, not AND, so you would want:

```
SELECT patient_id, patient_name FROM patient WHERE patient_id='p37' OR patient_id='p78' OR patient_id='p87'
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` keyword acts like an `OR` when you separate out the operands. Try replacing the `AND` in the second query with `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `OR` instead of `AND`.  patient_id cannot be 'p37' and 'p78' and 'p87' all at the same time.

```
SELECT patient_id, patient_name
FROM patient
WHERE patient_id='p37' OR patient_id='p78' OR patient_id='p87'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without more information, but can patient_id really be three things at once?

Perhaps you mean to use OR.

```
SELECT patient_id, patient_name
FROM patient
WHERE patient_id='p37' OR patient_id='p78' OR patient_id='p87'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT patient_id, patient_name
  FROM patient
 WHERE patient_id='p37' OR patient_id='p78' OR patient_id='p87'
```